# Sort entities in foreign key dependency order

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, .net-core, relational-database, entity-framework-core

I am working on a mechanism to seed a collection of tables via EF Core. How can I sort a DbContext's entities in order of foreign key dependencies? Since some tables have foreign keys, some tables need to be seeded before others. It seems like there would be a simple API for performing this sort, but all I have been able to find are a couple complex recursive T-SQL implementations.

I am sure there is a common solution for this type of problem that is prevalent, I just have been unable to locate it / know how to search for it.

**Update:**
Because EF Core doesn't seem to support [Merge/Upsert/AddOrUpdate](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4526) yet, I am going down the path of a database-specific (MySQL family in this case) raw SQL query. So, I have a method like below that I want to call for a collection of entities, but I need to call this method in order of the `TEntityType`'s foreign key dependencies. Since it is a raw SQL query and not an EF API, per se, I don't think EF can auto-magically update tables in the correct dependency order (in response to [@Gert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362913/ef-core-sort-entities-in-foreign-key-dependency-order#comment83719032_48362913)).

```
private static void InsertOnDuplicateKeyUpdate<TEntityType>(DbContext dbContext) where TEntityType : class
{
    var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntityType));
    var properties = GetPropertiesLessValueGeneratedTimestamps(entityType);
    var columns = string.Join(", ", properties.Select(x => x.Name));
    var values = CreateValues<TEntityType>(properties);
    var updates = CreateUpdates(properties);
    var rawSqlString = "INSERT INTO " + entityType.Relational().TableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES " +
                        values + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + updates;
    dbContext.Set<TEntityType>().FromSql(rawSqlString);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code or explain what you have tried so far? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: There's no API for this, you just need to understand your entity models and write your seed code in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG . That was the answer I was afraid of. I was really hoping for something a bit more automated where I wouldn't have to touch my seed algorithm every time a new entity is added (which should be infrequent, for sure).

Comment: Well, you would have to add to the see method anyway...

Comment: When you add all related entries (with the correct FK's/navigation properties set) to the context, EF has two pretty simple rules about the ordering of these inserts: 1. First the parent entry types are inserted, so no FK constraints, that are not failing in the context, will fail in the database, 2. In this ordering of classes, if the PK type implements IComparable, the lower PK values are inserted first. At least this was the case up until EF6, I don't see why they would have turned that off for core.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Which means: EF does it for you. Collin: just add entities to your context, making sure they have correct references to one another, and EF will figure out the insert/update/delete order.

Comment: Thanks, @DevilSuichiro , that makes sense. See my update with more info to understand more of my situation.

Comment: Thanks, @GertArnold , that makes sense. See my update with more info to understand more of my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core contains all information needed to sort entity types based on foreign key dependencies. The only issue I found when using EF Core as a source of table order is that same table references will need to be handled differently - whether it might be for example allowing inserting identifiers, disabling table triggers or some other way.

To grab a list of entity types from which you can get table names, DbSet etc, use the following function:

```
    private IList<IEntityType> GetDependentTables(IModel model)
    {
        var copied = new List<IEntityType>();
        var tables = model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.GetKeys().Any()).ToList();
        while (tables.Count > 0)
        {
            var copiedCount = copied.Count;
            for (var i = 0; i < tables.Count; i++)
            {
                var table = tables[i];
                if (table.GetForeignKeys().All(x => copied.Contains(x.PrincipalEntityType) || x.DeclaringEntityType == x.PrincipalEntityType))
                {
                    copied.Add(table);
                    tables.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (copiedCount == copied.Count)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Circular foreign keys found in remaining tables: " + string.Join(",", tables.Select(x => x.Name)));
            }
        }

        return copied.Where(x => x.BaseType == null).ToList();
    }
```

usage:

```
var tableEntityTypes = GetDependentTables(myDbContext.Model);
```